# Why can't I install bcrypt?

Tags: gem

I've a problem: when I try to install some Gem with the command "bundle install", I recive this output:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20141210-5447-g6skes.rb extconf.rb 
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/bcrypt-3.1.7/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Why? How can i solve it?

Comment: I deleted my answer since it didn't help you. I also upvoted your question since no one has given a solution. Good luck getting an answer, soz I can't help.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions `bcrypt-ruby` seems to use the GMP library.

Something like this should help:

```
sudo aptitude install libgmp-dev
```

Do not forget to install all the stuff for development:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```